# Python class attribute cannot be called within object scope

Tags: python

```
import pyodbc

class Database(object):

    def connect(self):
        connection = pyodbc.connect("""DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                       SERVER=XX\SQLEXPRESS;
                                       DATABASE=ACCOUNT_DBF;
                                       UID=sa;PWD=XXX""")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

    def check_account(self, usr):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TBL WHERE account = ?", usr)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        print(row[0])

database = Database()
database.check_account("developer")
```

So, as you can see I am trying to call the "check_account" function with the parameter of "developer". But whenever I execute/build it, it gives me an error of

> "NameError: name cursor not defined"

I am curious and new to python on how to actually do it. I've been searching around the web but I cannot find a specific answer for my problem.

*I am using the latest python btw(3.6.1).

Comment: But you never call `connect`, and even if you did you never return the cursor from that method or assign it to in instance variable, so it is lost.

Comment: you have not pass `cursor object` as a parameter to `check_account` function

Comment: @DanielRoseman your comment is not helping me sir. But thank you though.

Comment: @Surajano hi thank you for your comment. I do not think I need to pass it in the check_account function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NameError` exception is triggered because in the `check_account` method you can not see local variables defined in `connect` method.

You need to set instance attributes "inside" `self`, since you can access `self` from all methods (it is the instance itself).

```
def connect(self):
    self.connection = pyodbc.connect("""DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                   SERVER=XX\SQLEXPRESS;
                                   DATABASE=ACCOUNT_DBF;
                                   UID=sa;PWD=XXX""")
    self.cursor = connection.cursor()

def check_account(self, usr):
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TBL WHERE account = ?", usr)
    row = self.cursor.fetchone()

    print(row[0])
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much for the clear answer!

Comment: I would like to add another question to you regarding the "self." is it good to add "self." everytime in the class scope?

Comment: They are different things... When you define a function inside a class by default it is an instance method and every time that function is called it is passed the `self` first argument where you have the object itself. If you really want to have class methods you have to use `@classmethod` decorator and the first argument passed will be the Class, not the instance.

Comment: @JakeMcLaren Also notice that there is a huge difference in doing a class method and an instance method. My solution is using instance methods, so when you create a Database object, each object will have its own connection. If you do this as a class method and you have a connection class attribute, the same connection is shared for all the database objects. It depends on what you really want to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Database(object):

def connect(self):
    connection = pyodbc.connect("""DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                   SERVER=XX\SQLEXPRESS;
                                   DATABASE=ACCOUNT_DBF;
                                   UID=sa;PWD=XXX""")
    self.cursor = connection.cursor()
```

In your code, `cursor`is variable which below to method, only `self.cursor` can store cursor to class, and then other methods can use.

Comment: Hi there thank you for the comment. Indeed that will fix the cursor issue but. It will argue about the connection variable not being defined too. So what I did was put "self." in every variable.